# System.Net.Sockets tracing without app.config

Tags: c#, sockets, system.diagnostics

I need to set up tracing output from `System.Net.Sockets` at run-time without using the `app.config` file approach.

Setting up with stuff in `System.Diagnostics` part of the `app.config` works well, but since I need to have this on occasionally in the field I'd rather configure it in at run-time.

Comment: Can you use a third party tool like wireshark ?

Comment: I could if on site.. but what I'd really like to do is be able to get customers to generate a diagnostic output that can be sent back to me. Hence the need to turn on at runtime..  thanks

Comment: The users could change the app.config and then rerun the application.

Comment: *Could* .. unfortunately not customer friendly.. but a possibility.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar (dynamically enable tracing) on a large application I worked on a few years back. It is possible to do all in code. The basic idea is to compile with tracing enabled (i.e. set the TRACE conditional) and to initially set the default trace listener to the null output device. All trace info will go to the bit bucket.

When you want to enable tracing, you initialize and install a [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) that outputs the trace information where you want it to go.

The documentation at [Tracing and Instrumenting Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6s4h68%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows how to enable and configure tracing in code, without depending on the configuration file.

[How To: Configure Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx) explains the configuration file settings you need to make in order to enable network tracing. You have to re-cast that to do it in code. In particular, you'll need to create [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) and [TraceSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.traceswitch.aspx) instances that correspond to the sources and switches defined in that example configuration file.

It's certainly doable, although it takes a bit to wrap your head around all the different moving parts.

Comment: This is the direction I'm pointed at. "... need to create TraceSource and TraceSwitch instances that correspond to the sources and switches defined in that example configuration file." This is where I'm being blind. There is, e.g. 'private static bool System.Net.Logging.s_LoggingEnabled' which I'd like to toggle. What I cannot grasp at this stage is how to do something like that. I'll follow up your pointers. I've already played with switches and sources successfully. I just have not been able to 'find' the trace data from System.Net.Sockets except by using the app.config to set it up.  Thanks